# Call to a member function addDays() on null laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in laravel

```
if ( Carbon::now()->greaterThan($verifyUser->created_a->addDays(1)) )
```

The error is "Call to a member function addDays() on null"

That code is to check if the user did not verify on time within 24hrs. 
Thanks

Comment: change $verifyUser->created_at->addDays(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
if ( Carbon::now()->greaterThan($verifyUser->created_a->addDays(1)) )
```

to

```
if ( Carbon::now()->greaterThan($verifyUser->created_at->addDays(1)) )
```

if you are using `created_a`

then set the in your model

```
protected $dates = ['created_a'];
```